# Save the output of a powershell command in a variable and use it in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, fqdn

What I am trying to do is to save the output of a powershell command (run from a batch script) and use it in the batch script.

Can you please advise me what to do?

The power shell comand is:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName
```

I want to use the output in the batch script.

## P.S.

It will be even better if I can get the full computer name/hostname/fully qualified domain name (FQDN) from cmd and not from powershell. But the full computer name is not the concatenation of the ComputerName and the UserDNSDomain variables.

Comment: From powershell, '$env:computername' can get you the computer name if that's what you mean by your PS. 

@thufir I see the bounty is asking for a 100% powershell solution, but I don't see the batch code looking to be converted.

Comment: @thufir: I don't understand. The question is how to use the 100% powershell command from batch, so the question itself should be the answer, you are looking for. If it's not, please clarify or even better ask a new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell /command "[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName"') do set return=%%i
echo %return%
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in batch using `nslookup` which does the same DNS-search:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('nslookup hostname ^| findstr /i "name"') do set return=%%b
echo Hello '%return%'
```