# how to get the HostName from powershell?

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-core

How do I get the [hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42014215/262852) for `dur` from powershell?

```
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> ./hostname.ps1                                                                              
google.com
localhost
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> cat ./hostname.ps1                                                                          
$hosts = ("google.com", "localhost")

foreach($i in $hosts) {
  $fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($i).HostName
  write-host $fqdn
}
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> hostname                                                                                    
dur
PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```

The FQDN for the system is actually `dur.bounceme.net`, which would be the preferred output.

Comment: Usually the environment variable $env:Computername holds the hostname. I'm not sure if this variable also works on Linux (I don't have a Linux VM with Powershell installed on it to test this on at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bluuf for setting me on the [right track](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25305421/262852):

```
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName                                        
dur.bounceme.net
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> hostname                                                                                    
dur
PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```

Comment: Does it work for windows as well to get the hostname? It should, see the right track link..