# Batch file and SQLplus : compare results of 2 queries

Tags: batch-file, compare, sqlplus

[Resolved]
Hello, 
(sorry if my english is not exact i'm not english)
I'm using a "test" database and a "working" database
I would like to know how much results i have in my table "incident" in each database to compare 
I'm using SQLplus in a .bat file

I resolved the problem writing in only 1 text file (but you can do it with 2)
Write in resultat.txt the result of the query on the working database :

```
echo SELECT count(*) FROM table; | sqlplus -s user/password@dbprod > path\resultat.txt
```

Set in the variable return1 (i think the last line of) the content of resultat.txt :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (path\resultat.txt) do set return1=%%i
```

Same commands with the test

```
echo SELECT count(*) FROM table; | sqlplus -s user/password@dbtest > path\resultat.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (path\resultat.txt) do set return1=%%i
```

Here i overwrite the resultat.txt file but you can write in another text file
And now you can display and test the equality :

```
echo resultat prod : %return1%
echo resultat test : %return2%
if %return1%==%return2% ( 
echo IMPORT REUSSI 
) else ( 
ECHO IMPORT RATE 
) 
pause
```

Comment: Je suis sûr que vous auriez plus de réponse si vous auriez demandé en anglais. Comme les .bat n'offrent pas beaucoup, est-ce possible d'utiliser quelque-chose comme powershell?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179288/get-output-from-command-line-and-save-into-variable/46179429#46179429)

Comment: Oui je peux utiliser powershell par contre il faudrais que je "traduise" tout mon .bat en powershell non?

Comment: [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305537/2152082)

Comment: ok Thakns @stephan so i can use :   
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell /command "..."') do set return=%%i
echo %return%
   and replace by my powershell command

Comment: This is an English site, so you'll have to translate your question to English; otherwise it might likely get closed. Refer to this help article: [ask]

Comment: Translates done

Comment: Your last line looks fine. Define "doesn't work". Any errormessages? Wrong result? What do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: i expected to have the result of my query SELECT (example : 12345)

Comment: When i don't write "@echo off" I actually have a doc (SQLplus i think)

Comment: I have put a screenshot

Comment: the output in your linked image is the help of `sqlplus`. Which probably means, there is a syntax error with the `sqlplus` command. Try to use the `sqlplus` command on ith's own (without the surrounding `for`) and correct, until you get the correct output. * Then*  put the `for` around it.

Comment: I have fount another method : 
@echo SELECT count(*) FROM incident_demande; | sqlplus -s m_test/m_test@asisline_test > C:\path...\resultat.txt

Comment: It writes correctly in my files but there is the name of column, how should i take only the number?

Comment: you can use proper tokens and delims with a `for /f` loop with a [file content](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) or [a command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (sorry, I never worked with `sql`, so I don't know, how the output would look like to help you; If you can't manage it yourself, show the exact ouput of your command)

Comment: It's ok i resolved the problem i post the solution

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved] Hello,
(sorry if my english is not exact i'm not english)
I'm using a "test" database and a "working" database
I would like to know how much results i have in my table "incident" in each database to compare
I'm using SQLplus in a .bat file

I resolved the problem writing in only 1 text file (but you can do it with 2)
Write in resultat.txt the result of the query on the working database :

```
echo SELECT count(*) FROM table; | sqlplus -s user/password@dbprod > path\resultat.txt
```

Set in the variable return1 (i think the last line of) the content of resultat.txt :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (path\resultat.txt) do set return1=%%i
```

Same commands with the test

```
echo SELECT count(*) FROM table; | sqlplus -s user/password@dbprod > path\resultat.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (path\resultat.txt) do set return1=%%i
```

Here i overwrite the resultat.txt file but you can write in another text file
And now you can display and test the equality :

```
echo resultat prod : %return1%
echo resultat test : %return2%
if %return1%==%return2% ( 
echo IMPORT REUSSI 
) else ( 
ECHO IMPORT RATE 
) 
pause
```

Comment: It does not make sense to post the solution in both the question and the answer...